# vertex/object moving sensitivity increases suddenly

Tags: modeling

After working a while,suddenly if I try to move a vertex or an object, it moves too much.It is like, if I try to move a vertex freely in any direction, it moves .1 unit at a time at first.After working a while it starts to move 1 unit at a time.It does not fix if I hide any object that has too many object on the same project or even if i delete it.What to do?

Same thing happen with rotation and scale.

Comment: you must have enabled the snap option (magnet icon)

Comment: @moonboots Thanks.It worked.but this kept happening since my last few works which was quite irritating.Many thanks